# Possible to get check number with Yodlee API?

Tags: yodlee

The Yodlee API seems to return the following as a description of a check:

CHECK XXXXXXXXXX6789

What actually appears at the bank is something like:

CHECK 1234 123456789

Where 1234 is the check number. It seems like Yodlee is purposely obfuscating check number information, just curious if there is a way to get that which I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Yodlee do mask the numbers and show only last 4 digits. This is done for security reasons as the description may contain the account number of a user's account and hence the SDK returns only the last 4 digits.

There is a way to get the complete number but can be customized for a cobrand(SDK customer) and has to go through several approvals inside Yodlee and also with the client.

If you want to receive the complete number please log a service request through our YCC tool providing your cobrandID and other details and our customer support will look into it.

NOTE - If you have taken the SDKEE product then this can't be changed for you.